# Refreshing GStream videos after "zoom/unzoom"

Tags: c, video, gstreamer, gtk3, gtk2

My program is a copy of the [basic_tutorial-5.c](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/~slomo/gst-sdk-tutorials/tree/gst-sdk/tutorials/basic-tutorial-5.c), except I have modified it to play four videos at once in four separate windows in one box contained in the GTK environment. The videos play great with play, pause, and stop buttons as well as a slider bar to seek.I have also added a zoom and unzoom function. Selecting a zoom button will make one of the windows fill the screen. Ideally, selecting the unzoom button should restore all four videos, but only the recently "zoomed" window is displayed, the other three videos are black. I can then still select a different video to zoom and it will fill the screen and unzooming will display only the recently zoomed video.  The other videos will not reappear unless I select the stop button. How do I make the other videos "refresh" without having to select stop? Here is the code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <gst/video/videooverlay.h>
#include <gdk/gdk.h>
#include <gdk/gdkx.h>

typedef struct _CustomData {
  GstElement *pipe1,*pipe2,*pipe3,*pipe4; /* Four pipelines */

  GtkWidget *slider;
  GtkWidget *streams_list;
  gulong slider_update_signal_id;

  GstState state;
  gint64 duration;
} CustomData;

  GtkWidget *main_window;
  GtkWidget *vid_win1,*vid_win2,*vid_win3,*vid_win4;
  GtkWidget *main_box;
  GtkWidget *main_hbox1,*main_hbox2;
  GtkWidget *sub_hbox1;
  GtkWidget *controls;
  GtkWidget *play_button, *pause_button, *stop_button;
  GtkWidget *zb1,*zb2,*zb3,*zb4,*uzb1,*uzb2,*uzb3,*uzb4;
  gboolean   zoomed = FALSE;

static void realize_cb (GtkWidget *widget, GstElement *data) {
  GdkWindow *window = gtk_widget_get_window (widget);
  guintptr window_handle;

  if (!gdk_window_ensure_native (window))
    g_error ("Couldn't create native window needed for GstXOverlay!");

  window_handle = GDK_WINDOW_XID (window);
  gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle (GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(data), window_handle);

}

static void pause_cb (GtkButton *button, CustomData *data) {
  gst_element_set_state (data->pipe1, GST_STATE_PAUSED);
  gst_element_set_state (data->pipe2, GST_STATE_PAUSED);
  gst_element_set_state (data->pipe3, GST_STATE_PAUSED);
  gst_element_set_state (data->pipe4, GST_STATE_PAUSED);

}

static gboolean refresh_ui (CustomData *data) {
  GstFormat fmt = GST_FORMAT_TIME;
  gint64 current = -1;

  if (data->state < GST_STATE_PAUSED)
    return TRUE;

  if (!GST_CLOCK_TIME_IS_VALID (data->duration)) {
    if ((!gst_element_query_duration (data->pipe1, fmt, &data->duration)) ||
       (!gst_element_query_duration (data->pipe2, fmt, &data->duration))  ||
       (!gst_element_query_duration (data->pipe3, fmt, &data->duration))  ||
       (!gst_element_query_duration (data->pipe4, fmt, &data->duration))) {
      g_printerr ("Could not query current duration.\n");
    } else {
      gtk_range_set_range (GTK_RANGE (data->slider), 0, (gdouble)data->duration / GST_SECOND);
    }
  }

  if ((gst_element_query_position (data->pipe1, fmt, &current)) ||
      (gst_element_query_position (data->pipe2, fmt, &current)) ||
      (gst_element_query_position (data->pipe3, fmt, &current)) ||
      (gst_element_query_position (data->pipe4, fmt, &current))) {
    g_signal_handler_block (data->slider, data->slider_update_signal_id);
    gtk_range_set_value (GTK_RANGE (data->slider), (gdouble)current / GST_SECOND);
    g_signal_handler_unblock (data->slider, data->slider_update_signal_id);
  }
  return TRUE;
}


static void zoom_cb (GtkButton *button, CustomData *data) {

  if (!(zoomed)) {

    g_object_ref (zb1);
    gtk_container_remove (GTK_CONTAINER(sub_hbox1),zb1);
    g_object_ref (zb2);
    gtk_container_remove (GTK_CONTAINER(sub_hbox1),zb2);
    g_object_ref (zb3);
    gtk_container_remove (GTK_CONTAINER(sub_hbox1),zb3);
    g_object_ref (zb4);
    gtk_container_remove (GTK_CONTAINER(sub_hbox1),zb4);

    if (button == (GTK_BUTTON(zb1))){
      g_object_ref (vid_win2);
      gtk_container_remove (GTK_CONTAINER(main_hbox1), vid_win2);
      g_object_ref (main_hbox2);
      gtk_container_remove (GTK_CONTAINER(main_box), main_hbox2);
      gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (sub_hbox1), uzb1, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
      gtk_widget_show_all (main_box);
    } else
        if (button == (GTK_BUTTON(zb2))){
      g_object_ref (vid_win1);
      gtk_container_remove (GTK_CONTAINER(main_hbox1), vid_win1);
      g_object_ref (main_hbox2);
      gtk_container_remove (GTK_CONTAINER(main_box), main_hbox2);
          gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (sub_hbox1), uzb2, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
          gtk_widget_show_all (main_box);
    } else
        if (button == (GTK_BUTTON(zb3))){
          g_object_ref (vid_win4);
          gtk_container_remove (GTK_CONTAINER(main_hbox2), vid_win4);
          g_object_ref (main_hbox1);
          gtk_container_remove (GTK_CONTAINER(main_box), main_hbox1);
              gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (sub_hbox1), uzb3, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
              gtk_widget_show_all (main_box);
        } else
            if (button == (GTK_BUTTON(zb4))){
              g_object_ref (vid_win3);
              gtk_container_remove (GTK_CONTAINER(main_hbox2), vid_win3);
              g_object_ref (main_hbox1);
              gtk_container_remove (GTK_CONTAINER(main_box), main_hbox1);
                  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (sub_hbox1), uzb4, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
                  gtk_widget_show_all (main_box);
                }
  zoomed = TRUE;
  gtk_widget_show_all (main_window);
  gtk_widget_realize (main_window);
  }
} // zoom_cb

static void unzoom_cb (GtkButton *button, CustomData *data){

  if (zoomed) {
    if (button == (GTK_BUTTON(uzb1))){
      g_object_ref (uzb1);
      gtk_container_remove (GTK_CONTAINER(sub_hbox1), uzb1);
      gtk_box_pack_end (GTK_BOX (main_hbox1), vid_win2, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
      gtk_box_pack_end (GTK_BOX (main_box), main_hbox2, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
      g_object_unref (vid_win2);
      g_object_unref (main_hbox2);
      gtk_widget_show_all (vid_win2);
      gtk_widget_show_all (main_hbox1);
      gtk_widget_show_all (main_hbox2);
      gtk_widget_show_all (main_box);
    } else
        if (button == (GTK_BUTTON(uzb2))){
          g_object_ref (uzb2);
          gtk_container_remove (GTK_CONTAINER(sub_hbox1), uzb2);
          gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (main_hbox1), vid_win1, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
          gtk_box_pack_end (GTK_BOX (main_box), main_hbox2, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
          g_object_unref (vid_win1);
          g_object_unref (main_hbox2);
          gtk_widget_show_all (vid_win1);
      gtk_widget_show_all (main_hbox1);
      gtk_widget_show_all (main_hbox2);
          gtk_widget_show_all (main_box);
        } else
          if (button == (GTK_BUTTON(uzb3))){
            g_object_ref (uzb3);
            gtk_container_remove (GTK_CONTAINER(sub_hbox1), uzb3);
            gtk_box_pack_end (GTK_BOX (main_hbox2), vid_win4, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
            gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (main_box), main_hbox1, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
            g_object_unref (vid_win4);
            g_object_unref (main_hbox1);
            gtk_widget_show_all (vid_win4);
            gtk_widget_show_all (main_hbox1);
            gtk_widget_show_all (main_hbox2);
            gtk_widget_show_all (main_box);
          } else
            if (button == (GTK_BUTTON(uzb4))){
              g_object_ref (uzb4);
              gtk_container_remove (GTK_CONTAINER(sub_hbox1), uzb4);
              gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (main_hbox2), vid_win3, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
              gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (main_box), main_hbox1, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
              g_object_unref (vid_win3);
              g_object_unref (main_hbox1);
              gtk_widget_show_all (vid_win3);
              gtk_widget_show_all (main_hbox1);
              gtk_widget_show_all (main_hbox2);
              gtk_widget_show_all (main_box);
          }
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (sub_hbox1), zb1, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (sub_hbox1), zb2, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (sub_hbox1), zb3, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (sub_hbox1), zb4, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
    gtk_widget_show_all (main_window);
    gtk_widget_show_all (vid_win1);
    gtk_widget_show_all (vid_win2);
    gtk_widget_show_all (vid_win3);
    gtk_widget_show_all (vid_win4);
    zoomed = FALSE;
  }
} // unzoom

static void play_cb (GtkButton *button, CustomData *data) {
  gst_element_set_state (data->pipe1, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  gst_element_set_state (data->pipe2, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  gst_element_set_state (data->pipe3, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  gst_element_set_state (data->pipe4, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
} // play_cb


static void stop_cb (GtkButton *button, CustomData *data) {
  gst_element_set_state (data->pipe1, GST_STATE_READY);
  gst_element_set_state (data->pipe2, GST_STATE_READY);
  gst_element_set_state (data->pipe3, GST_STATE_READY);
  gst_element_set_state (data->pipe4, GST_STATE_READY);
} // stop_cb

static void delete_event_cb (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEvent *event, CustomData *data) {
  stop_cb (NULL, data);
  g_signal_connect (widget, "destroy", G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);
  gtk_main_quit ();
} // delete_event

static gboolean expose_cb (GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventExpose *event, CustomData *data) {
  if (data->state < GST_STATE_PAUSED) {
    GtkAllocation allocation;
    GdkWindow *window = gtk_widget_get_window (widget);
    cairo_t *cr;

    gtk_widget_get_allocation (widget, &allocation);
    cr = gdk_cairo_create (window);
    cairo_set_source_rgb (cr, 0, 0, 0);
    cairo_rectangle (cr, 0, 0, allocation.width, allocation.height);
    cairo_fill (cr);
    cairo_destroy (cr);
  }

  return FALSE;
}

static void slider_cb (GtkRange *range, CustomData *data) {
  gdouble value = gtk_range_get_value (GTK_RANGE (data->slider));
  gst_element_seek_simple (data->pipe1, GST_FORMAT_TIME, GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH | GST_SEEK_FLAG_KEY_UNIT,
      (gint64)(value * GST_SECOND));
  gst_element_seek_simple (data->pipe2, GST_FORMAT_TIME, GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH | GST_SEEK_FLAG_KEY_UNIT,
      (gint64)(value * GST_SECOND));
  gst_element_seek_simple (data->pipe3, GST_FORMAT_TIME, GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH | GST_SEEK_FLAG_KEY_UNIT,
      (gint64)(value * GST_SECOND));
  gst_element_seek_simple (data->pipe4, GST_FORMAT_TIME, GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH | GST_SEEK_FLAG_KEY_UNIT,
      (gint64)(value * GST_SECOND));

}

static void create_ui (CustomData *data) {

  main_window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (main_window), "delete-event", G_CALLBACK (delete_event_cb), data);

  vid_win1 = gtk_drawing_area_new ();
  vid_win2 = gtk_drawing_area_new ();
  vid_win3 = gtk_drawing_area_new ();
  vid_win4 = gtk_drawing_area_new ();

  gtk_widget_set_double_buffered (vid_win1, FALSE);
  gtk_widget_set_double_buffered (vid_win2, FALSE);
  gtk_widget_set_double_buffered (vid_win3, FALSE);
  gtk_widget_set_double_buffered (vid_win4, FALSE);

  g_signal_connect (vid_win1, "realize", G_CALLBACK (realize_cb), data->pipe1);
  g_signal_connect (vid_win2, "realize", G_CALLBACK (realize_cb), data->pipe2);
  g_signal_connect (vid_win3, "realize", G_CALLBACK (realize_cb), data->pipe3);
  g_signal_connect (vid_win4, "realize", G_CALLBACK (realize_cb), data->pipe4);

  g_signal_connect (vid_win1, "expose_event", G_CALLBACK (expose_cb), data->pipe1);
  g_signal_connect (vid_win2, "expose_event", G_CALLBACK (expose_cb), data->pipe2);
  g_signal_connect (vid_win3, "expose_event", G_CALLBACK (expose_cb), data->pipe3);
  g_signal_connect (vid_win4, "expose_event", G_CALLBACK (expose_cb), data->pipe4);

  play_button = gtk_button_new_from_stock (GTK_STOCK_MEDIA_PLAY);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (play_button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (play_cb), data);

  pause_button = gtk_button_new_from_stock (GTK_STOCK_MEDIA_PAUSE);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (pause_button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (pause_cb), data);

  stop_button = gtk_button_new_from_stock (GTK_STOCK_MEDIA_STOP);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (stop_button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (stop_cb), data);

  data->slider = gtk_hscale_new_with_range (0, 100, 1);
  gtk_scale_set_draw_value (GTK_SCALE (data->slider), 0);
  data->slider_update_signal_id = g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (data->slider), "value-changed", G_CALLBACK (slider_cb), data);

  zb1 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Zoom1");
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (zb1), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (zoom_cb), data);
  zb2 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Zoom2");
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (zb2), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (zoom_cb), data);
  zb3 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Zoom3");
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (zb3), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (zoom_cb), data);
  zb4 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Zoom4");
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (zb4), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (zoom_cb), data);
  uzb1 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Unzoom1");
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (uzb1), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (unzoom_cb), data);
  uzb2 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Unzoom2");
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (uzb2), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (unzoom_cb), data);
  uzb3 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Unzoom3");
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (uzb3), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (unzoom_cb), data);
  uzb4 = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Unzoom4");
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (uzb4), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (unzoom_cb), data);

  sub_hbox1 = gtk_hbox_new (FALSE, 0);

  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (sub_hbox1), zb1, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (sub_hbox1), zb2, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (sub_hbox1), zb3, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (sub_hbox1), zb4, FALSE, FALSE, 0);

  data->streams_list = gtk_text_view_new ();
  gtk_text_view_set_editable (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (data->streams_list), FALSE);

  controls = gtk_hbox_new (FALSE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (controls), play_button, FALSE, FALSE, 2);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (controls), pause_button, FALSE, FALSE, 2);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (controls), stop_button, FALSE, FALSE, 2);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (controls), data->slider, TRUE, TRUE, 2);

  main_hbox1 = gtk_hbox_new (FALSE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (main_hbox1), vid_win1, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_end (GTK_BOX (main_hbox1), vid_win2, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
  main_hbox2 = gtk_hbox_new (FALSE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (main_hbox2), vid_win3, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_end (GTK_BOX (main_hbox2), vid_win4, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

  main_box = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (main_box), main_hbox1, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (main_box), main_hbox2, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_end (GTK_BOX (main_box), controls, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_end (GTK_BOX (main_box), sub_hbox1, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (main_window), main_box);
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (main_window), 1280, 720);

  gtk_widget_show_all (main_window);
} // create_ui


static void tags_cb (GstElement *pipe1, gint stream, CustomData *data) {
  gst_element_post_message (pipe1,
    gst_message_new_application (GST_OBJECT (pipe1),
      gst_structure_new ("tags-changed", NULL)));
}

static void error_cb (GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, CustomData *data) {
  GError *err;
  gchar *debug_info;

  gst_message_parse_error (msg, &err, &debug_info);
  g_printerr ("Error received from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), err->message);
  g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
  g_clear_error (&err);
  g_free (debug_info);

  gst_element_set_state (data->pipe1, GST_STATE_READY);
  gst_element_set_state (data->pipe2, GST_STATE_READY);
  gst_element_set_state (data->pipe3, GST_STATE_READY);
  gst_element_set_state (data->pipe4, GST_STATE_READY);
} // error_cb

static void eos_cb (GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, CustomData *data) {
  g_print ("End-Of-Stream reached.\n");
  gst_element_set_state (data->pipe1, GST_STATE_READY);
  gst_element_set_state (data->pipe2, GST_STATE_READY);
  gst_element_set_state (data->pipe3, GST_STATE_READY);
  gst_element_set_state (data->pipe4, GST_STATE_READY);
} // eos_cb

static void state_changed_cb (GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, CustomData *data) {
  GstState old_state, new_state, pending_state;
  gst_message_parse_state_changed (msg, &old_state, &new_state, &pending_state);
  if (GST_MESSAGE_SRC (msg) == GST_OBJECT (data->pipe1)) {
    data->state = new_state;
    g_print ("State set to %s\n", gst_element_state_get_name (new_state));
    if (old_state == GST_STATE_READY && new_state == GST_STATE_PAUSED) {
      refresh_ui (data);
    }
  }
}

static void analyze_streams (CustomData *data) {
  gint i;
  GstTagList *tags;
  gchar *str, *total_str;
  guint rate;
  gint n_video;  // n_audio, n_text; disregarding audio and subtitle for now
  GtkTextBuffer *text;

  text = gtk_text_view_get_buffer (GTK_TEXT_VIEW (data->streams_list));
  gtk_text_buffer_set_text (text, "", -1);

  g_object_get (data->pipe1, "n-video", &n_video, NULL);

  for (i = 0; i < n_video; i++) {
    tags = NULL;
    g_signal_emit_by_name (data->pipe1, "get-video-tags", i, &tags);
    if (tags) {
      total_str = g_strdup_printf ("video stream %d:\n", i);
      gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor (text, total_str, -1);
      g_free (total_str);
      gst_tag_list_get_string (tags, GST_TAG_VIDEO_CODEC, &str);
      total_str = g_strdup_printf ("  codec: %s\n", str ? str : "unknown");
      gtk_text_buffer_insert_at_cursor (text, total_str, -1);
      g_free (total_str);
      g_free (str);
      gst_tag_list_free (tags);
    }
  }

}

static void application_cb (GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, CustomData *data) {
  if (g_strcmp0 (gst_message_type_get_name (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(msg)), "tags-changed") == 0) {
    if (gst_message_has_name (msg, "tags-changed")) {
      analyze_streams (data);
    }
  }
}  

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  CustomData data;
  GstStateChangeReturn ret1,ret2,ret3,ret4;
  GstBus *bus1,*bus2,*bus3,*bus4;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  memset (&data, 0, sizeof (data));
  data.duration = GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE;

  data.pipe1 = gst_element_factory_make ("playbin", "play1");
  data.pipe2 = gst_element_factory_make ("playbin", "play2");   
  data.pipe3 = gst_element_factory_make ("playbin", "play3");
  data.pipe4 = gst_element_factory_make ("playbin", "play4");

  if ((!data.pipe1) || (!data.pipe2) || (!data.pipe3) || (!data.pipe4)) {
    g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
    return -1;
  }

  /* Set the URI to play */
//  g_object_set (data.playbin, "uri", "http://docs.gstreamer.com/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm", NULL);
  g_object_set (data.pipe1, "uri", "file:///home/useruseron/vdtest/hrtstcd1.mp4", NULL);
  g_object_set (data.pipe2, "uri", "file:///home/useruseron/vdtest/hrtstcd3.mp4", NULL);
  g_object_set (data.pipe3, "uri", "file:///home/useruseron/vdtest/hrtstcd5.mp4", NULL);
  g_object_set (data.pipe4, "uri", "file:///home/useruseron/vdtest/hrtstcd7.mp4", NULL);

  /* Connect to interesting signals in playbin */
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (data.pipe1), "video-tags-changed", (GCallback) tags_cb, &data);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (data.pipe2), "video-tags-changed", (GCallback) tags_cb, &data);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (data.pipe3), "video-tags-changed", (GCallback) tags_cb, &data);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (data.pipe4), "video-tags-changed", (GCallback) tags_cb, &data);

  create_ui (&data);

  bus1 = gst_element_get_bus (data.pipe1);
  gst_bus_add_signal_watch (bus1);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus1), "message::error", (GCallback)error_cb, &data);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus1), "message::eos", (GCallback)eos_cb, &data);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus1), "message::state-changed", (GCallback)state_changed_cb, &data);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus1), "message::application", (GCallback)application_cb, &data);
  gst_object_unref (bus1);

  bus2 = gst_element_get_bus (data.pipe2);
  gst_bus_add_signal_watch (bus2);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus2), "message::error", (GCallback)error_cb, &data);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus2), "message::eos", (GCallback)eos_cb, &data);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus2), "message::state-changed", (GCallback)state_changed_cb, &data);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus2), "message::application", (GCallback)application_cb, &data);
  gst_object_unref (bus2);

  bus3 = gst_element_get_bus (data.pipe3);
  gst_bus_add_signal_watch (bus3);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus3), "message::error", (GCallback)error_cb, &data);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus3), "message::eos", (GCallback)eos_cb, &data);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus3), "message::state-changed", (GCallback)state_changed_cb, &data);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus3), "message::application", (GCallback)application_cb, &data);
  gst_object_unref (bus3);

  bus4 = gst_element_get_bus (data.pipe4);
  gst_bus_add_signal_watch (bus4);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus4), "message::error", (GCallback)error_cb, &data);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus4), "message::eos", (GCallback)eos_cb, &data);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus4), "message::state-changed", (GCallback)state_changed_cb, &data);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (bus4), "message::application", (GCallback)application_cb, &data);
  gst_object_unref (bus4);

  ret1 = gst_element_set_state (data.pipe1, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  ret2 = gst_element_set_state (data.pipe2, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  ret3 = gst_element_set_state (data.pipe3, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  ret4 = gst_element_set_state (data.pipe4, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  if ((ret1 == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) || (ret2 == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) ||
      (ret3 == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) || (ret4 == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE)) {
    g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
    gst_object_unref (data.pipe1);
    gst_object_unref (data.pipe2);
    gst_object_unref (data.pipe3);
    gst_object_unref (data.pipe4);

    return -1;
  }

  g_timeout_add_seconds (1, (GSourceFunc)refresh_ui, &data);

  gtk_main ();

  gst_element_set_state (data.pipe1, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_element_set_state (data.pipe2, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_element_set_state (data.pipe3, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_element_set_state (data.pipe4, GST_STATE_NULL);

  gst_object_unref (data.pipe1);
  gst_object_unref (data.pipe2);
  gst_object_unref (data.pipe3);
  gst_object_unref (data.pipe4);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. The question is well written, but you posted quite a long code, which may be fine in some cases but I cannot compile it (in pause_cb, the pipe2 is undefined). Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if possible please shorten the code.

Comment: ok I checked whats the problem and found out that you were trying to shorten the code to fit in 300 000 chars on SO making it not-compilable.. you better fix it and if it doesnt fit you can remove some comments.. after fixing few things I can compile and reproduce your problem..

Comment: I reposted compilable code. If someone is trying to make it work, they would need to substitute four videos and the paths to those videos in URI g_object_set definitions.

Comment: cflags and libs used to compile are gstreamer-plugins-base-1.0 gtk+-2.0 gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0

Comment: I made changes to my local copy to be gtk3 compliant and I still saw the same results. However, after I had zoomed and unzoomed and one video was visible in its original position, I grabbed the edge of the window and expanded it and quickly all the other videos were visible. So how do I send an "expand"  or redraw with the current dimentions signal to gstreamer to refresh the videos without doing an actual expand? Or would that be a gtk signal?

Comment: I am sometimes getting segfault `double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000001ade720 ***` upon clicking zoom, also one of the videos is strangely zoomed, you know why?

Comment: I have not seen that segfault error. All four of my videos are the same length (1 hour 40 minutes) and resolution (1920 x 1080). Perhaps the one video has a different resolution. I will need to maintain same duration videos but I may need to test with different resolutions as my ultimate task will probably need to accommodate different resolution videos. Is there a way to force Gstreamer to refresh a video? Part of the documentation (or sample code comment) stated Gstreamer will refresh the video while paused or playing.

Comment: I am using the same video for all four views.. maybe you can stop and play the pipeline

Comment: Also see my answer on the GStreamer mailing list: https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/gstreamer-devel/2016-March/057064.html
If you ask questions in multiple places, make sure to mention that so people don't waste their time answering something that you already got answered elsewhere.